# Python Implement AES in CBC encryption mode

Tags: python, encryption, aes, pycrypto, cbc-mode

I'm trying to complete [this](http://cryptopals.com/sets/2/challenges/10) challenge online which asks to implement ourselves the AES CBC mode without using any library function that will do the job for me (ofc xD). I'm using `python3.7` and `PyCrypto` for the AES modules (I'm a python beginner btw)

I'm at a point where I feel like I found the solution but it's not the case, I don't see what I'm doing wrong.
I'm entering this text: `

> In september 2017 In september 2017 In september 2017 In september
>   2017

`
with this key:

> YELLOW SUBMARINE

and with an 16 bytes long IV full of 0 (\x00)

but my ouput differs from the different websites I can find online or when using the AES CBC mode from the `PyCrypto` module

here's the small program that I made so far in order to generate my aes cbc encryption with comments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from sys import argv
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import codecs


def pad(plaintext):
    padding_len = 16 - (len(plaintext) % 16)
    print(padding_len)
    if padding_len == 16:
         return plaintext
padding = bytes([padding_len] * padding_len)
return plaintext + padding


def xor_for_char(input_bytes, key_input):
    index = 0
    output_bytes = b''
    for byte in input_bytes:
        if index >= len(key_input):
            index = 0
        output_bytes += bytes([byte ^ key_input[index]])
        index += 1
    return output_bytes


class AESCBCTool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.best_occurence = 0
        self.best_line = 0

def encrypt_CBC(self, enc, key):
    enc = pad(enc) # here I pad the text (PCKS#7 way)
    nb_blocks = (int)(len(enc) / 16) #calculate the number of blocks I've to iter through
    IV = bytearray(16)
    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
    for i in range(nb_blocks):
            enc2 = xor_for_char(enc[i * 16:(i + 1) * 16], IV) #xor a block with IV
            IV = cipher.encrypt(enc2) # set the the IV based on the encryption of the xored text
            print(codecs.decode(codecs.encode(IV, 'base64')).replace("\n", ""), end='') #print the encrypted text in base 64


def main(filepath):
    f = open(filepath, "r")
    if f.mode == 'r':
        content = f.readlines()
        tool = AESCBCTool()
        for line_content in content:
            tool.encrypt_CBC(bytes(line_content, "utf-8"), bytes("YELLOW SUBMARINE", "utf-8"))
    f.close()


if __name__== "__main__":
    try:
        main(argv[1]) #this is the path to the file that contains the text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        exit(84)
    exit(0)
```

here's my output:

> 0TKm+DjGff6fB/l0Z+M5TQ==8do1FSVvjbN2+MhAULmjHA==w5vZtuiL2SrtSLi2CkMBzQ==nvKLm7C7QDmSxk2PqV3NHQ==2+DSu4BqXskn8/znFCUCcQ==

meanwhile the output should be:

> IS4p7kpY9g0a68AUzpKzazbtbP0h3nYZvhptuxNajBS3KIUHGI3fu79e4fw+E34miyn5dMBle8Tqn2DvHsromy7AupMy0zbtlqPwU5uHoyY=

Do you have any advice for me please?

Comment: Your pkcs7 padding is incorrect, your base64 encoding needs to be done on the entire output, not on each individual block.

Comment: Thanks, it worked once I encoded in base64 the whole output instead.